# Enabling VSync in Vulkan

Tags: c++, c, vsync, vulkan

How do I use vsync in Vulkan? I'm on Windows, but the code should also work on Linux. Is it implemented by inserting a fence in `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Though you could realize that by using a fence the correct way would be to use a presentation mode that waits for the vertical blank like VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR.

Intel has a great article that contains a detailed look at Vulkan's different presentation modes [over here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-2?language=en#_Toc445674479)

Note that this mode may not be available on every device and that some drivers may ignore the v-sync even if you select a corresponding presentation mode. So if you use one of these modes and don't get v-sync you may have to wait for a newer driver.

But if it's implemented inside the driver this is the correct way of doing v-sync across all platforms supported by Vulkan.

Comment: FIFO is the one mode that is always available

Comment: Technically yes, at is required to be supported by the specs. But you should still have a fallback and don't rely on the presence of VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR, e.g. if you're running on non-conformant drivers or implementations.